# Vector to Elements in ClojureScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, clojure, clojurescript

I have a vector:

```
(def my-collection ["image1.jpg" "image2.jpg" "image3.jpg"])
```

And I would like to make 3 images in document.

```
(println (count my-collection)) ; this prints count of my collection. This is 3.

(map (fn [x] (println x)) my-collection) ; doesn't do anything!
```

But!

```
(def image-element (.createElement js/document "img"))
(def insert-into-body (.appendChild (.-body js/document) image-element))
(set! (.-src image-element) "image1.jpg")
```

This code works perfectly for one element!

What I should do for a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` function is used to transform a collection to another by applying the specified function. Since `(println x)` returns `nil`, the result of your code will be `(nil, nil, nil)` with side-effect (each image name is printed in your console).

Perhaps you want to define a function to create an image element with specified src.

```
(defn create-image [src]
  (let [img (.createElement js/document "img")]
    (set! (.-src img) src)
    img))
```

Now, you can provide the collection to map the image name to image element, then append them into body element.

```
(doseq [i (map create-image my-collection)]
  (.appendChild (.-body js/document) i))
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `map` is also lazy by default and is most of the time not what you're looking for if you want to cause side effects.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's beautiful solution!